# CSS transform rotate effects on duplicated element instead of actual one

Tags: css, reactjs, electron

I have a problem where CSS Transform Rotate generates a new element and rotates it overlapping the actual one when I dynamically add the class to the element.

And if I set default rotate(deg) to element. The animation works fine.

I have no idea whether this is a feature or issue of CSS.

I build this element in Electron by ReactJS. Is it related to WebKit of Electron?

```
.parent-class > .btn-demo {

  background: url(image.png) no-repeat center center;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;    

  // if add default degree then it works fine
  // transform: rotate(0deg);
}

.parent-class.animated > .btn-demo {
  // it will copy a new element and overlap real one
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```